# How to get all Quarkus application configuration properties and their values?

Tags: quarkus, smallrye

I would like to generate a list of my application configuration values, with their description and default values. Just like quarkus has for the framework itself on https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config, but for my application properties.

Would it be possible to achieve this using the SmallRye Config or Quarkus APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quarkus does not have an official support for this. This has been discussed, and there is even an issue to add it properly at some point: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/19020

At your own risk, you can add the `quarkus-extension-processor` to your project and annotate the mappings with `@ConfigRoot(phase = ConfigPhase.RUN_TIME)`(it still requires the `@ConfigMapping`), which will generate the `adoc` files used by Quarkus for its own configuration.